# Paypal sandbox not returning data

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I implemented a paypal checkout about 3 years ago and it is currently working well. I now want to create a new checkout page for a new set of items. I copied the code from the page that I previously used and updated it for the new items. I set up the new page to use my sandbox for initial testing. The code below is cut from the actual page for display here.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
  <form id='paypal_form' action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
  <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="buyer@test.com" />
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="non-member RTV Renewal" />
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="75.00" />
  <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="Id=Joe;fixedName=Joe Smith;pw=1234;email=buyer@google.com;expdate=2024-02-14" />
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US" />

  <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://www.roundalab.org/Figures_Subscriptions_All/test_renew.htm">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.roundalab.org/Figures_Subscriptions_All/success_test.php">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
  <center>
    <div id="add-cart" style="padding:30px;">
      <button onClick="document.getElementById('paypal_form').submit();">Click Here To Submit Order To Paypal</button>
    </div>
  </center>
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The code works and creates an order in the paypal sandbox. It is then supposed to go the the url in the "return' item, which it does. The problem is that paypal is supposed to return a bunch of data in $_POST. When the return page is displayed, $_POST is empty. I also display $_GET and it contains 1 field which is the payer_id. A couple of questions...

Anyone know why no data in $_POST?
Is there a way that I can get any kind of error message that shows info on why no POST data was sent when going to the url in the return item?
I assume that this method of using paypal is deprecated. Is there a place that I can still get to the docs for using this interface?

Answer (score 1):

The receiving sandbox Business account needs to enable [Payment Data Transfer](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/) for any data to be returned.

With this sort of HTML-only (no API) PayPal integration that redirects away from your site, a return after a completed transaction is never guaranteed to occur. PayPal may be obligated to show the payer a receipt, or they may never click to return, or their browser may be closed or crash. Therefore, you should not depend on this returned data for absolutely anything of any importance. It is for extra informational purposes only.

If you are trying to do anything important with data returned via _GET/_POST , your integration is flawed.

---

With such an HTML-only <form> post integration, the only reliable way to receive data is by implementing the IPN service, which is also very old.  All of these are poor choices if you need to do anything important with the data being returned.

---

Instead, use a current PayPal Checkout integration. Follow the [Set up standard payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/) guide and make 2 routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). Both routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller.

Pair those 2 routes with the frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server